# Referential Integrity violation

Tags: c#, database, referential-integrity

I´m getting the next error message:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

Basically I have two classes, Type and Device.

```
public class Device
{
    [Key]
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Type DeviceType { get; set; 
}
```

and:

```
public class Type
{
    [Key]
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

How can I delete a Type in my programm without having problems with the databases?

Comment: What is a message of inner exception?

Comment: What do you want to happen to `Device`s that have that `Type`, when you delete it?

Comment: maybe you must delete all Device having this type before delete the type

Comment: I want to keep the devices in the database

Comment: That´s the problem, I want to keep the devices and not deleting them

Answer (score 0):

You would have to delete all the Devices using that type first... Or disable the foreign key first

Comment: I need to keep the devices.

Comment: If you delete the Type, then what would you like all devices which DID have that type before it was deleted to have in their Type column after?

Comment: You can just disable the foreign key to allow you to do this - but you would be making the database design worse... Presumably the foreign key is there for a reason

Comment: I agree with you, there must be a way to delete an object without having this problem

Comment: As I mentioned - The way is to disable or remove the foreign key constraint... However you probably don't want to do this. First you must change the type on all the devices using that type to a different type, or remove those devices... Read up on what a Foreign Key is for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key

Comment: I appreciate your help, I will go ahead and check it out

Answer (score 0):

You have a foreign key between `Device` and `Type`. Depending on how you have set it up, a device may or may not have a type, but once a device *has* a type, your database will not allow you to delete *that type*, because what would the type of *that* device be then?

Your options are:

- Do not delete types. Just add a boolean field to note whether the type is active or not.
- Delete types only after you updates all devices with what you want (set them to no type? Delete them too?)

Comment: Thanks for the help!, I was thinking about that, every Device must have a type.

Comment: Is there not a way to delete type completely ?

Comment: Sure, just remove it from all devices first. Then you can delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the help!